# What exactly does FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND do when sending ordered broadcasts?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast

What exactly does FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND do when sending ordered broadcasts?

Does it actually speed up anything or does it simply tell the receiver that you have less time to do your stuff or I'll be angry?

It says:

> If set, when sending a broadcast the recipient is allowed to run at
>   foreground priority, with a shorter timeout interval. During normal
>   broadcasts the receivers are not automatically hoisted out of the
>   background priority class.

What does

> with a shorter timeout interval

mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This raises the priority of the `Thread` that is running the `BroadcastReceiver`, which will allow it to get more CPU cycles than competing threads of lower priority. This may speed things up if there are a lot of competing threads.

Comment: OK, so it actually speeds something up? Upon network disconnect (maybe a lot of stuff going on then?) I got response time (for easy task) of 25 seconds for an ordered broadcast call, but when I added this flag it came down to 11 seconds. I was afraid it was just the timeout of the broadcastreceiver or something but that isn't the case if we get the response OK, right?

Comment: Yes, it will raise the priority of the thread running the `onReceive()` method so that it completes more quickly, as it will no longer compete with background threads for CPU cycles. Assuming that each of the `BroadcastReceiver`s process the `onReceive()` quickly, you should be OK. I'm not sure what you mean by "if we get the response OK"

Comment: I was referring to pendingResult().setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK), and being able to retrieve that from the other end. Strange thing I got it but after 25 seconds! Thought something would have timed out by then. Long story short. I was afraid something was wrong with how I handled my ordered broadcasts because it could take so long for them to get a response. And when I set the flag it came down, but still to a long 11 seconds...

Comment: When you send an ordered broadcast, it will go to ALL interested receivers, serially, one after another. Are you sure there is only ONE registered receiver?

Comment: Also, in an ordered broadcast, if one of the receivers times out I do not think that this has any effect on the status. It simply calls the next one in the list

Comment: It's also worth noting that there are also separate message queues for foreground and background broadcasts. So emmiting a foreground intent would not only benefint from a BroadcastReceiver running with at least foreground priority but also from a message queue with potentially less contention.